# Errors in older R package due to class(x) returning, both, matrix and array - is this new?

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, version

I am working with an older package called `PIMixture` ([see here](https://dceg.cancer.gov/tools/analysis/pimixture)) which throws me a lot of errors at various spots of the code. They all look like this or similar (the following lines are actually from the reproducible example):

```
> library(PIMixture)
> data(PIdata)
> model<-"C_CIN3PLUS+L_CIN3PLUS+R_CIN3PLUS~RES_HPV16"
> fit1<-PIMixture(p.model=model,data=PIdata1, model="logistic-Weibull")
Error in if (class(mat2) == "numeric") { : the condition has length > 1
```

Upon investigation I found out that

```
> class(mat2)
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

and hence the if clause returns an error. I cannot believe this was an issue when the package was developed because it would have been noticed. Hence I wonder if in earlier versions of R `class(mat2)` perhaps evaluated to `"Matrix"` only, hence having length 1. I can apply fixes in the source code of `PIMixture` that look like this: `class(mat2)[1]`. Not nice, but then the package works. I wonder if this is issue occurs due to a change in R across versions or why this problem may occur.

Comment: A more robust fix would be  `"numeric" %in% class(mat2)` (or `is.numeric(mat2)`).  [This package](https://github.com/CBIIT/R-PIMixture/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) appears to have absolutely no unit testing, any vignettes or even a read me.  All in all, the error you descibe, together with the lack of documentation and testing, would make me very cautious about relying on its results.

Comment: perhaps you're looking for `storage.mode(mat2) == "numeric"` ?

Comment: Report it to the maintainer as listed in the DESCRIPTION file or if you can't wait get the source and change `if (class(mat2) == "numeric")` to `if (inherits(mat2, "numeric"))`

Comment: @Limey and all others, sorry for late reply as I was out of office. Thanks also for the suggestions on stable fixes. I implemented one that works for me for now. Regarding reliability of the package and lack of testing: yes, but note it is work published in one of the best statistics journals (AOAS; DOI: 10.1214/17-AOAS1036). So there was some testing (see e.g. the simulations in that paper). My question however is more related to why this problem suddenly occured, as I am sure this package once worked (e.g. at time of publication.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour changed in R version 4.0.0 or 4.2.0, depending on what you consider to be the "change".  `news(Version == "4.0.0")` says:

> `matrix` objects now also inherit from class `"array"`, so e.g., `class(diag(1))` is `c("matrix", "array")`.  This invalidates code incorrectly assuming that `class(matrix_obj))` has length one.

`news(Version == "4.2.0")` says:

> Calling `if()` or `while()` with a condition of length greater than one gives an error rather than a warning.  Consequently, environment variable `_R_CHECK_LENGTH_1_CONDITION_` no longer has any effect.

Why not use `is.matrix` or `is.numeric` instead?  (It is hard to say what test is appropriate without seeing the logic of the function.)

See also Martin Mächler's blog post from 2019: [*When you think `class(.) == *`, think again!*](https://blog.r-project.org/2019/11/09/when-you-think-class.-think-again/index.html)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I will inform the package maintainer of this issue and made a post on the github reporting the problem.